# org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie not serializable?

Tags: groovy, httpclient, serializable

I am quite confused... I am reading here and BasicClientCookie *clearly* implements Serializable per JavaDoc:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.html

However, my simple Groovy script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.0.1')
)
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie
import java.io.File

def cookie=new BasicClientCookie("name","value")
println cookie instanceof Serializable
def f=new File("/tmp/test")
f.withObjectOutputStream() { oos->
    oos.writeObject(cookie)
}
```

outputs:

```
false
Caught: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie
        at t$_run_closure1.doCall(t.groovy:12)
    at t.run(t.groovy:11)
```

I have checked and I have no other versions of HttpClient anywhere in classpath (if I take Grapes statement out it cannot find file).

Thank you!
Misha Koshelev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc you linked to is for httpclient 4.1 alpha, but you are using httpclient 4.0.1.

Check the source, it confirms the Serializable interface was added in between [4.0.1](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.0.1/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.java) and the [trunk](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/BasicClientCookie.java).